# what are two different meanings I can get from this sentence?

Tags: sentence-meaning

Sally didn't eat more than two apples.

I am wondering how does this sentence can get two different meanings.

Comment: What is your interpretation of the sentence? Why do you believe there are two meanings? If you explain your thinking we might be able to give better answers.

Comment: Because of two different structure ambiguity... One meaning is the case when 'didn't' is only attached to the verb 'eat'('more than two apples' wold not be in the syntactic domain of 'didn't'), and the other meaning is the case when 'more than two' is in the syntactic domain of 'didn't'.

Comment: Would I be correct in assuming that this is a homework question? Perhaps start off by listing the meaning that you can see, and we can work on the second one from there.

Comment: Yes this is one of my homework question but I am not a native speaker and I decide to ask to native speakers.

Comment: I can see one structure with the case when 'didn't' is only attaching to the verb 'eat'. But I am not sure about the meaning...

Comment: Am I understanding you correctly in that you're differentiating between different emphases, e.g. Sally only *eating* two apples (but buying four nonetheless) vs. Sally eating *only* two apples (even though she claimed she was very hungry)? — Edit: Perhaps I shouldn't have changed the wording; the emphases I used would be "didn't *eat* more than" and "didn't eat more than *two*" in the original sentence.

Comment: The meaning can change with stress, e.g. if "apples" is stressed, it implies Sally might have eaten more than two of something else. If you stress "Sally", it implies someone else ate all those apples... and so on.

Comment: what does the meaning of                                         "more than two apples, Sally didn't eat."

Comment: Is there additional context to the homework question that you did not mention? And what subject are you studying here?

Comment: @user3169 I'd guess English, since the posted sentence and associated question aren't likely to be encountered outside of learning it.

Comment: @DamienH I meant more specifically, such as some specific  grammar topic.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless how you slice it (or them...), the sentence:

> Sally didn't eat more than two apples.

by itself can only mean one of these:

> Sally ate two apples.
>   Sally ate one apple.
>   Sally ate no apples.

Referring to whole apples, anyway.

Comment: But if she did slice them, she might have eaten 1-1/2, or 1-3/4.  Also, stress matters, as DrMoishe Pippik pointed out.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock I would like to see some example sentences where emphasis would mean something else, but you cannot imply anything not in the statement itself.

Comment: DrMoishe Pippik gave examples.

Comment: "emphasis" refers to spoken English. I was not referring to written English. There, you have to take it literally, in one of the three ways user3169 listed.